# scrapy IndexError: list index out of range but yes in scrapy shell

Tags: python, scrapy, data-extraction

Why would url = response.urljoin(link[0]) would produce 'IndexError: list index out of range' error? I understand what this error means.However, when i run the code in scrapy shell,it's ok. Why? Please help...

items.py

```html
import scrapy


class HuxiuspiderItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    title = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()
    desc = scrapy.Field()
    posttime = scrapy.Field()
```

spider.py

```html
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from huxiuspider.items import HuxiuspiderItem

class HuxiuspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "huxiuSpider"
    allowed_domains = ["www.huxiu.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.huxiu.com/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath("//div[@class='mod-info-flow']/div/div[@class='mob-ctt']"):
            item = HuxiuspiderItem()
            item['title'] = sel.xpath('h3/a/text()').extract_first()
            item['link'] = sel.xpath('h3/a/@href').extract()
            link = sel.xpath('h3/a/@href').extract()
            url = response.urljoin(link[0])
            item['desc'] = sel.xpath('div[@class="mob-sub"]/text()').extract_first()
            print (item['title'],item['link'],item['desc'])
            #print url
```

the results of run the spider

```html
D:\pythonweb\scrapytest\huxiu\huxiuspider>scrapy crawl huxiuSpider
2016-07-13 10:34:12 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.1.0 started (bot: huxiuspider)
2016-07-13 10:34:12 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'huxiuspider.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['huxiuspider.spiders'], 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'BOT_NAME': 'huxiuspider'}
2016-07-13 10:34:12 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2016-07-13 10:34:13 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.chunked.ChunkedTransferMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2016-07-13 10:34:13 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2016-07-13 10:34:13 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2016-07-13 10:34:13 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2016-07-13 10:34:13 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-07-13 10:34:13 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6024
2016-07-13 10:34:13 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.huxiu.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2016-07-13 10:34:13 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.huxiu.com/> (referer: None)
(u'\u51db\u51ac\u5c06\u81f3\uff1f\u5899\u5012\u4f17\u4eba\u201c\u8870\u201d\u4e4b\u4e0b\uff0c\u7ebf\u4e0b\u96f6\u552e\u51fa\u8def\u5728\u54ea\u91cc', [u'/article/156013/1.html'], u'\u7ebf\u4e0a\u53d1\u5c55\u662f\u8d8b\u52bf\u6240\u5411\uff0c\u4f46\u6211\u4eec\u9700\u8981\u770b\u5f97\u66f4\u8fdc')
(u'\u4e1c\u65b9\u68a6\u5de5\u5382\u53c8\u53cc\u53d2\u53d5\u6362\u5e05\u4e86\uff0c5\u5e743\u4efbCEO\u662f\u95f9\u54ea\u6837', [u'/article/156000/1.html'], u'\u8bf4\u767d\u4e86\u8fd8\u662f\u5728\u4e4e\u4e2d\u56fd\u5e02\u573a\u5457')
(u'\u8425\u9500\u4e0a\u7279\u7acb\u72ec\u884c\u7684\u5c0f\u7c73\uff0c\u4e3a\u4f55\u6389\u8fdb\u7fa4\u661f\u4ee3\u8a00\u7684\u4fd7\u5957\u8425\u9500\u602a\u5708\uff1f', [u'/article/156007/1.html'], u'\u8fd9\u6216\u662f\u5c0f\u7c73\u4e00\u6b21\u91cd\u8981\u7684\u54c1\u724c\u91cd\u5851')
(u'\u4e07\u8fbe9.21\u4ebf\u82f1\u9551\u5e76\u8d2d\u6b27\u6d32\u7b2c\u4e00\u5927\u9662\u7ebf\uff0c\u738b\u5065\u6797\u662f\u8981\u4e70\u4e0b\u5168\u4e16\u754c\uff1f', [u'/article/156002/1.html'], u'Odeon & UCI\u9662\u7ebf\u3002')
2016-07-13 10:34:13 [scrapy] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://www.huxiu.com/> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 588, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "D:\pythonweb\scrapytest\huxiu\huxiuspider\huxiuspider\spiders\huxiuSpider.py", line 16, in parse
    url = response.urljoin(link[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
2016-07-13 10:34:13 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2016-07-13 10:34:13 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 486,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 22755,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 13, 2, 34, 13, 917000),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/ERROR': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'spider_exceptions/IndexError': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 13, 2, 34, 13, 254000)}
2016-07-13 10:34:13 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

the results in scrapy shell are ...

```html
D:\pythonweb\scrapytest\huxiu\huxiuspider\huxiuspider\spiders>scrapy shell "http://www.huxiu.com/"
2016-07-13 10:30:37 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.1.0 started (bot: huxiuspider)
2016-07-13 10:30:37 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'huxiuspider.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'scrapy.dupefilters.BaseDupeFilter', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['huxiuspider.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'huxiuspider', 'LOGSTATS_INTERVAL': 0}
2016-07-13 10:30:37 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2016-07-13 10:30:37 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.chunked.ChunkedTransferMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2016-07-13 10:30:37 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2016-07-13 10:30:38 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2016-07-13 10:30:38 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2016-07-13 10:30:38 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2016-07-13 10:30:38 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.huxiu.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2016-07-13 10:30:38 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.huxiu.com/> (referer: None)
[s] Available Scrapy objects:
[s]   crawler    <scrapy.crawler.Crawler object at 0x03EEEF30>
[s]   item       {}
[s]   request    <GET http://www.huxiu.com/>
[s]   response   <200 http://www.huxiu.com/>
[s]   settings   <scrapy.settings.Settings object at 0x03EEE630>
[s]   spider     <HuxiuspiderSpider 'huxiuSpider' at 0x462dd50>
[s] Useful shortcuts:
[s]   shelp()           Shell help (print this help)
[s]   fetch(req_or_url) Fetch request (or URL) and update local objects
[s]   view(response)    View response in a browser
>>> ress = response.xpath("//div[@class='mod-info-flow']/div/div[@class='mob-ctt']")
>>> link = ress[0].xpath('h3/a/@href').extract()
>>> url = response.urljoin(link[0])
>>> url
u'http://www.huxiu.com/article/156013/1.html'
```

As seen, the url is right...

I know it's ok if i use ...

```html
            
            item['title'] = sel.xpath('h3/a/text()').extract_first()
            item['link'] = sel.xpath('h3/a/@href').extract_first()
            
            url = response.urljoin(item['link'])
            item['desc'] = sel.xpath('div[@class="mob-sub"]/text()').extract_first()
            print (item['title'],item['link'],item['desc'])
```

I'm wondering about the difference between the shell debug and scrapy spider run.Please help...

Comment: I had the same problem, each time I got a random number IndexError on different URLs, but when I debug those URLs with the same code inside scrapy shell there is no error. What was your solution in the end ?

Answer (score 0):

> Why would url = response.urljoin(link[0]) would produce 'IndexError: list index out of range' error?

Because `link` is an empty list.

> However, when i run the code in scrapy shell,it's ok

Show us how you run the code when this error happens.

Comment: Thank you. I get the ideas inspired from you .

Answer (score 0):

Why would url = response.urljoin(link[0]) would produce 'IndexError: list index out of range' error?
Because link is an empty list.
When the code is run, it won't extract anything meet the conditions of xpath. So, the link is an empty list, IndexError occured: list index out of range.

Answer (score 0):

This Will work for you try this

```
link = sel.xpath('.//h3/a/@href').extract()
```